# custom transactional email special characters issue

Tags: transactional-mail, character-encoding

I have an issue with transactional emails with special characters (é, è, à, etc.)

For the "Official Emails" such as "order_new.html" which are sent by magento core, everything works fine and all the special characters are well displayed in the mailbox.

But for custom transactional emails I define in Backend and send using custom modules special characters are not displayed correctly

ex : `Ã©tÃ© vÃ©rifiÃ©s avec succÃ¨s`

I tried defining utf-8 encoding both in email template and in the module code with `setHeader()`, but I have the same result.

Here is my code :

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
        ->setToName($ToName)
        ->setToEmail($ToEmail)
        ->setHeader('Content-type', 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8')
        ->setBody($processedTemplate)
        ->setSubject('tototototo')
        ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
        ->setFromName($senderName)
        ->setType('html');
```

Comment: Did you fix it ? :) Facing the same issue

Comment: see below. I use zend mail

Answer (score 5):

I managed to find a solution by using Zend Mail :

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
$mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
$mail->setBodyHtml($processedTemplate);
$mail->setFrom($senderEmail, $senderName);
$mail->addTo($ToEmail, $ToName);
$mail->setSubject('I love UTF8');
```

If it can help...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Ashroder_SMTPPro](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension) module, and you use the @Alexglvr's approach above, you'll always be sending emails using sendmail (instead the configured method on SMTPPro).

If you want to use your configured SMTP Settings in Ashroder's module, you may want to do something like:

```
$transport = null;
//if Aschroder is enabled, we try to get the transport configured in the admin. Otherwise, it will use default sendmail.
if(Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Aschroder_SMTPPro')){
    $helper = Mage::helper('smtppro');
    $transport = $helper->getTransport();
}
//Confimation E-Mail Send
$mail->send($transport);
```